# ajax file name is being sent as binary

Tags: php, ajax

I've a simple form which accepts few inputs as well as file,

**HTML**

```
<form class="mainfrom" id="mainfrom" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible infomsg" style="display:none">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Please Wait..!</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible error_show" style="display:none">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong class="error_msg"></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="quoteform">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <label> <span tooltip="Upload the file for which you require our services." flow="right">
                            Upload File <span class="question">?</span> </span>
            </label>
            <input type="file" id="myFile" class="form-control" name="filename1">
            <span id="myFileErr" class="error"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-1" value="Submit" name="submitquote"
                           id="submitquote">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My ajax code is as follow

```
var fd = new FormData($('#mainfrom')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: 'include/common.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: fd,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
})
.done(function (res) {
    if (res.status) {
        blah
        blah
    }
);
```

Oh php side I'm receiving file as  `$tmpName = $_FILES['filename1']['tmp_name'];`

However in chrome when I see data of the form it says filename1: (binary), **I need filename here*** because of which I think I'm not able to get filename in php, hence my ajax failing, 
How do I solve this?

**common.php**

```
$tmpName = $_FILES['filename1']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['filename1']['name'];

if (file_exists($tmpName) == true) {
    $curtime = time();
    $fileName = $_FILES['filename1']['name'];
    $fileExt = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $fileName = $curtime . '-' . rand('11111', '99999') . '.' . $fileExt;
    $folder = 'uploads/';

    if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $folder . '' . $fileName) == true) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you get filename by $_FILES['filename1']['name']

the uploaded file usually contain

- name: "a.png" => filename here
- type: "image/png" => file extension
- tmp_name: "/tmp/phpolpEjn" => where file uploaded on server
- error: 0 => upload error flag
- size: 149974 => file size

so if you want to check file exist you do it by:

`if (file_exists($_FILES['filename1']['tmp_name']`))

Comment: look at my updated code please, i think you've caught the issue, but how do I solve this? I need to check if file exist

Comment: if you need to check file exist, you check tmp_name index, so it's become if(file_exists($tmpName))

Comment: It was like that only, its not working, what do I need to change?

Comment: It got to do something with the file, you have caught it right, i need to trigger mail after uploading file

Comment: It was silly, I just had to do $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for uploads folder, error was over there, thanks